# size of an object reference in Javascript V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, size, v8

Does anyone know the size of an object reference in Javascript (V8). It's 8 bytes like in C pointers?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as I remember it takes 8 bytes. Nowadays it's the optimal size in x64 systems for all pointers/references.

Comment: Not sure of this. In some virtual machines, references are "intelligent", and increases the size depending on the number of objects to reference. If there is a few objects, the references can be quite small, and memory is saved. I do not know which is the case of V8 virtual machine. It would help to know it.