# Manage multiple Popups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help in managing multiple named popups created via window.open(). There are multiple popups all with a unique ID and my application requires some popups be reloaded after an ajax success in the parent window.

```js
var myWindow = window.open("_url", uniqueId, "other params...")
```

if I create a single popup, it can be reloaded by calling `myWindow.location.reload()`. However, I am not sure how it can be done as the reference to the current popup in `myWindow` object gets updated everytime a new popUp is opened.

I was thinking of maybe creating a global javascript map with `window.open` references in it. 
something like:

```js
var myWindowArray = [];
myWindowArray[uniqueId] = window.open("_url", uniqueId, "other params...");
```

and later reload this popup by calling `myWindowArray[uniqueId].location.reload()`.

I am not sure if this will work or if there is a better method for managing such circumstances.

Thanks in advance

Comment: with "uinque id" you mean that each popup has an id that is different from all the others?

Comment: yes! every popup will always have a unique ID

Answer (score 1):

The following is what you are looking for

```
var dict = {};
dict["MY_FIRST_WINDOW"] = window.open("_url", "MY_FIRST_WINDOW", "other params...");
dict["MY_FIRST_WINDOW"].location.reload();
```

but you say `I am not sure if this will work`, and that is a problem. You should always try things on your own first before asking.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about the scalability of such a design and less about feasibility. There may be 20-30 popups opened at once and the current DOM is already quite heavy.  I think I should have explained it a bit better

Comment: The object literal has nothing to do with the dom, and when you are doing `dict['UUID'] = window.open()` you are not storing the DOM of the window or copying its content to the `dict` rather storing a reference to it, which is 8 bytes according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32538987/614277